# How to create url for generic template without view?

Tags: python, django

I'm using `{% url path_to_view %}` to generate links within my application. I came to the situation when I need to use several static pages without views, using `direct_to_template`. Normally, if I had just one such page, I could use `{% url direct_to_template %}` to generate link to it, but with more URLs pointing to this view, `{% url direct_to_template %}` always points to the last one in `urls.py`.

Is it possible to use `{% url %}` syntax to point directly to some template? Or is the only choice to use views even if I don't really need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have django 1.3 use the class bases generic views, and you should create at least a url pattern

url.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^path/to/something/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="your_temlate.html"), name="something" ),
    url(r'^path/to/something/else/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="your_temlate_else.html"), name="something_else" ),
)
```

template:

```
<a href="{% url something %}">Link to something</a>
<a href="{% url something_else %}">Link to something else</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [named urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).
if you have

`url(regex=r'path/$', view=view_name, name='my_url'),`

they you can use `{% url my_url %}` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TemplateView`

```
url(r'^path_to_html/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="path_to_html.html"), name='path_to_html'),
```